# Blue Screen of death Windows XP 64 Bit Installation

Tags: windows-xp, bsod

I am having difficulty installing Windows XP 64 Bit to my custom PC, Always getting BSOD.

**My PC Specs**

```
Asus Extreme VI Maximus
4770k
1 SSD
1 2TB WD HD
32GB Ram(4x8GB)
```

**Disc**

```
Windows XP Professional x64 Edition
June 2006
Systems
Student Media / Work At Home Media
```

After entering the disc from boot, I get a normal blue screen like the following

Windows Setup

At the bottom I see progress such as

```
...
Setup is loading files (Video Card)
...
...
Setup is loading files (FAT FILE SYSTEM)...
...
Setup is starting Windows
```

It is always after *Setup is starting Windows* that the BSOD as follows appears.

```
A problem has been detected and windows has been shut down to prevent damage to your computer.
...
Technical information: ***STOP: 0x0000007B,(0xFFFFFADE5DE5D8323C0,0xFFFFFFFFC0000034,0x0000000000000000,0x0000000000000000)
```

**Some things I have tried to fix this**

- I have tried unplugging the SSD
- Unplugging the HD
- Removing 3 of the ram sticks leaving 1 8GB
- Removing 2 of the ram sticks leaving 2 8GB
- Putting the ram in different slots
- Moving the HD/SSD and CD drive to different SATA ports
- Removing the Overclock settings on my motherboard.
- Secure boot is off.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Your problem is connected to your hardware.  It does not and likely cannot be made to support Windows XP.

Comment: @Ramhound I've had this issue a few times in the past, always due to not loading the correct SATA RAID drivers. 0x7B stands for: INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE.

Answer (score 2):

Error code 0x7B means inaccessible boot device.  This is due to the fact that XP does not have a driver for your storage controller.  You probably have a SATA drive.

You have 3 options here:

1. Place the drivers on a floppy disk (yes, a classic 3.5" floppy) and use the F6 key during Windows setup to load the drivers from it.
2. Slipstream the drivers into the XP media and re-burn a custom XP install disc (instructions on Google for this are plentiful).
3. Place the SATA controller in IDE mode in your BIOS.  This is the easiest solution.

Comment: I tried 3, Still getting the exact same BSOD msg after "Setup is starting windows".

Comment: @cecilli0n Well if option 3 didn't work, use 1 and/or 2.  Since you're using such a weird beast as XP 64-bit, the driver support is *HORRIBLE*.  You'll need to give XP a _64-bit_ driver for the controller.  To do this, you'll need to find an XP 64-bit compatible driver for your hard drive controller, which Asus does not offer for your board (they offer NO XP-specific drivers).  Use a newer OS -- one from this decade. ;)

Comment: It is not sufficient to switch it into IDE mode after-the-fact.  You have to already have it in IDE mode when you install the OS.  Also, if the HDD is an advanced-format drive or modern SSD, it may very well not be able to operate in IDE mode.

Comment: What do you mean *not sufficient to switch it into IDE mode after-the-fact* and *have to have it in IDE mode*.
Once I get BSOD, I cannot edit the BIOS from here. I reboot into BIOS, edit the settings to IDE, save BIOS, reboot from CD. I dont understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: I was just saying that you have to reinstall Windows after you change it.  You can't save a machine that is getting the BSOD by changing the setting.

Comment: @WesSayeed Ok i c, However I never get as far as installing the first time around, let along reinstalling.

Comment: Setting the SATA controller in IDE mode still worked for me eight years later ;-) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error, its usually because you have setup your harddisk to be SATA RAID, but setup was unable to find the right driver and the BSoD is caused because it tries it with default drivers and fails.

During setup press F6 and load the required SATA RAID drivers.

alternatively (but only if you really can't) you can change to not use the RAID controller, but instead use it the SATA connectors without any form of RAID. This means the RAID controller is deactivated and certain speed optimizations are not in effect slowing things down.

Comment: tried to use IDE but still gives the exact same BSOD msg, Would secureboot being set to off or UEFI/Legacy BIOS mode effect this?

Comment: You did install windows XP AFTER you switched to IDE, right?

Comment: Yes. I rebooted, entered BIOS, changed setting to IDE, saved and rebooted. Same BSOD msg appeared.

Comment: I miss the part where you say that you then reformatted and installed windows xp again. If you really did, make sure you are using the correct RAID drivers using F6 and a floppy.

Comment: I wasnt aware that anything was being installed on the HD at this stage? I thought everything was being loaded.
If that is not the case, then I have been wasting my time with each attempt as there must be files/config left over on the HD from the previous

Comment: The reformat takes place during setup. If setup weren't able to continue, it would not find the harddrive to begin with. You're talking about it doing its thing, then a reboot and then the BSoD comes. That means it uses a driver to access the RAID but later fails. Switching to IDE will require you to do setup again from start to finish, and reformat the partition.

Answer (score 0):

I should question you on the why of wanting XP on such a machine. But disregarding that:

What you need to install Windows XP on a newer machine is to update XP installation media first.

There's a lot to be said about all the steps of this, but what you basically need is to integrate these driver packs,

http://driverpacks.net/

into your installation media, or get a .iso with the driver packs already integrated.

They have a tool on that website that should help you integrate the packs easily.

Answer (score -1):

Uncheck use host I/O cache. works with IDE controller. I only had to do this for windows XP x64 professional.

Answer (score -2):

Blue screens are very often linked to memory problems. (they can be more but most common)  I would recommend running a memory test. Try this -- > http://www.memtest86.com/

Run it and see if it comes across with any errors. If it does then replace your memory and if not then work down the line of components that could be affected.  Blue screens are always shown when there is a hardware problem so you basically need to keep testing components until you find the bad guy :)

Comment: This is a wrong thing to say. It gives a stopcode 0x7B and googling that gives the reason for the failure, and its not memory related at all.

Answer (score -2):

I locked out my DVD/CD drive and installed the program successfully from a old CD drive using a non-SATA connection. Worked.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by “I locked out my DVD/CD drive”?  When you say “program”, do you mean “operating system”?  (If not, what do you mean?)